# Why a minimal uncountable well ordered set $S_\omega$ exists?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Sorry for this dumb question.

If that set exists, why can't we just remove an element from that set to obtain a smaller but still uncountable and well ordered set? Or have I misunderstand the definition of minimal?

Thank you.

Comment: Why make your question so complicated? Why didn't you just ask, "why a minimal ***infinite*** well ordered set $\omega$ exists"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Minimal" here means with minimal *order type*.

Yes, you can remove an element to produce a well-ordered proper subset of the same cardinality, but this subset may still be *order-isomorphic* to the set you started out with -- and therefore count as "the same" for the purposes of interpreting "minimal" here.

(The minimal uncountable well-order type is usually called $\omega_1$ rather than $S_\omega$, though).

Answer (score 1):

Acutally, if you remove a point from $S_\omega$, you will obtain a set which has the same size.  The new set will be of the same order type as that of $S_\omega$ and so will not be considered a smaller set.